# Prove $(3+\sqrt{11})^{1/3}$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I can't say I've gotten very far. You can show $3 + \sqrt{11}$ is irrational, call it $a$. Then I tried supposing it's rational, i.e.:

$a^{1/3}$ = $\frac{m}{n}$ for $m$ and $n$ integers.

You can  write $m$ and $n$ in their canonical factorizations, then cube both sides of the equation...but I can't seem to derive a contradiction.

Comment: To be clear, have you already shown that $3 + \sqrt{11}$ is irrational? Because then you are basically done. Cubing a rational number gives you a rational number, so if $a^{1/3}$ were rational, then $a$ would be as well.

Comment: If $a$ is irrational and $a = (a^{1/3})^3 = (m/n)^3 = m^3/n^3$ with $m$ and $n$ integers, doesn't that imply that $a$ is rational as well?

Comment: Stahl I meant that I tried supposing it was rational and then deriving a contradiction. Yes @Dylan I've shown that $a$ is irrational. But I don't know how to show its cubed root is. I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the last sentence you typed out there to this. EDIT: Okay I see what you're getting at. But that's actually really the question I'm asking. Like how do we derive that contradiction?

Comment: $an^{3}$ = $m^{3}$. Now what?

Comment: There is no now what. $a = m^3 / n^3$, so $a$ is a ratio of two integers. But we already know that this is impossible because we showed earlier that $a$ is irrational. So we already have a contradiction. We don't have to go any further.

Comment: Oh I guess that is true. Was over thinking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(3 + \sqrt{11})^\frac{1}{3}=\frac{p}{q}$ were a rational, then $3 + \sqrt{11}=\frac{p^3}{q^3}$ would also be a rational.

Answer (score 1):

If you denote $x = (3 + \sqrt{11})^{\frac 13}$, you can show that the equation $x^6 - 6x^3 - 2 = 0$ holds and appeal to Rational Root Theorem.

[Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

**Rational Root Theorem**

> If $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$, where all of the $a_i$ are integers, and $P\left( \dfrac uv \right)=0$ where $u$ and $v$ are integers, then $v \mid a_n$ and $u \mid a_0$.

Let $x = (3 + \sqrt{11})^{\frac 13}$. Then
\begin{align}
   x^3 &= 3 + \sqrt{11} \\
   x^3-3 &= \sqrt{11}\\
   x^6 - 6x^3 + 9 &= 11 \\
   x^6 - 6x^3 - 2 &= 0 \\
\end{align}

According to the rational root theorem, the only possible rational zeros of the polynomial $P(x) = x^6 - 6x^3 - 2$ are $1, -1, 2,$ and $-2$.

We find $P(1) = -7$, $P(-1)=-5$, $P(2)=14$ and $P(-2)=110$

Hence $P(x) = x^6 - 6x^3 - 2$ has no rational roots. It follows that 
$x = (3 + \sqrt{11})^{\frac 13}$ is irrational.